# Prevent content from wrapping around floated element

Tags: css

I am well aware of the concept of "overflow" in HTML/CSS. But here I am stuck at a very simple issue.

```css
    #wrapper {
      width: 100%;
    }
    aside {
      width: 30%;
      text-align: justify;
      float: left;
    }
    section {
      width: 70%;
      text-align: justify;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <aside>Aside</aside>
  <section>Section</section>
</div>
```

My wrapper div consists of aside and section.I tried to align them side by side with total width of the container. But it always appear that section overflows.I wonder why? The total width of aside plus section has never crossed width of its wrapper container.It only works if I put `overflow:hidden` in the section.

Comment: Have you thought to substract the padding from the width with `calc(width - padding)`

Comment: Did you use padding for the section or aside?

Comment: I have not added any padding to my code.

Comment: What do you mean by "section overflows"? Can you provide a test case that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Can't seem to see any overflow in the example. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: try adding float left to section also checkout https://jsfiddle.net/bcpj5hch/

Comment: For better explanation can you please provide the url?

Comment: @DavidDomain, actually there is no overflow in the code. But the issue was not giving any float to section. float:right in section did the trick.- thanks

Comment: @RahulS, actally I am working on local host. So i don't have a url to provide. But as i mentioned, I manged to understand my mistake. ANy way, thank you.

Comment: if you mean to aside in one end and section in other end... you can give first one float:left and other one float:right;text-align:right also. Then both will go in both opp ends...no need of overflow actually...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do to overcome the effect of the `section` overflowing is to set `overflow` to `auto` on the section. Now you will not need to set `float` on the `section`,...

```css
#wrapper {
      width: 100%;
    }
    aside {
      width: 30%;
      text-align: justify;
      float: left;
      background: green;
    }
    section {
      width: 70%;
      text-align: justify;
      overflow:auto;
      background: red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <aside>Aside</aside>
  <section>Section Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere illo pariatur odit! Nobis impedit quibusdam a explicabo quod in molestias amet nemo fugiat excepturi nisi placeat ex est sequi distinctio.</section>
</div>
```

but be aware of the fact that if the content (any child elements) of `section` are extending the boundary of `section` will cause scrollbars on the `section`. So keep that in mind. You could as well use `overflow:hidden` which will work as well in your situation, but then any content that exceeds the boundary of `section` will be hidden. In case of `overflow:hidden` you could do the following to prevent this behavior. An example with an `image` as a child element of `section` could look like this.

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
aside {
    width: 30%;
    text-align: justify;
    float: left;
    background: green;
}
section {
    width: 70%;
    text-align: justify;
    background: yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
}
section img {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <aside>Aside</aside>
  <section>Section Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere illo pariatur odit! Nobis impedit quibusdam a explicabo quod in molestias amet nemo fugiat excepturi nisi placeat ex est sequi distinctio.
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" />
  </section>
</div>
```